# node.js javascript function to return result out of Promise action

Tags: javascript, node.js

My conclusion it cannot be done on js on node.js after a long search and try out.

one example (good for all Promises examples):

I need to develop a generic JS function to get a linux command and return the result , the result is the output out of the linux command (example : pwd   output: /home/jery)

The function need to wait for the result since the next command line after that need it's output - so the **programming is serial one**.

I can do a loop to wait for the Promise to complete but endless loop will consume CPU , and nodejs does not have a real sleep command.

```
result1 = shell("pwd")
result2 = shell("ls " + result1)
```

This shell linux is just an example , I have the same need for function that just call a url , or function that get an sql query from mysql server.
The main point is serial programming - so solution must comply.

Just to give another example , the shell() function will be called hundred of times and waiting for that many promises to complete is not an option , thus the output of one need to be the input of others.

thank you
j.r

Trying to serialize a Promises function result in high cpu while waiting.

Comment: I'm **really** not sure what you are asking here. Are you looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await ?

Comment: You can't make an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one. Your code would probably cleaner and clearer if you use `await` to wait for Promise resolution in one or more `async` functions.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking, but it *sounds like* there's just a general misunderstanding of asynchronous operations (Promises, et al) and how to use them.

Comment: `after a long search` , `it cannot be done`   Executing multiple shell commands with the result of another shell command can certainly be done in `node.js`, I think your conclusion is incorrect.

Comment: Quentin
In this solution I will not be able to return value out of function.

Comment: David: do you have an example?

Comment: Keith: I don't see answer to my question , do you have ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

async function runShellCommand(command) {
  const {
    stdout,
    stderr
  } = await exec(command);
  return stdout
}

runShellCommand("dir").then(result => {
    console.log(result)
})
```

With this code I was able to print the output of the dir command using the return value `result`. This answers the first part of your question on capturing the output of a shell command. Trying to make a synchronous function out of an asynchrounous one is not only hard and impractical to do but the solution will also most likely be some hack that you should try to avoid

Comment: Hi Isak, this solution will not give me the option to wrap it in a function returning value, thank you

Comment: `runShellCommand` is the function. To get the value returned from it without using `.then` you should call it using await

Answer (score 0):

Save your file as `foo.mjs`, and this also works (adapted from @Isak The Hacker)

```js
import { promisify } from 'node:util';
import { exec } from 'node:child_process';

const execPromise = promisify(exec);

const {
  stdout,
  stderr
} = await execPromise(command);

console.log(stdout);
```

Comment: kic@ip-172-31-40-254:~/kic/code/admin/util/sandbox$ cat test1.mjs 
import { promisify } from 'node:util';
import { exec } from 'node:child_process';

const execPromise = promisify(exec);

var command = "ls -l"

const {
  stdout,
  stderr
} = await execPromise(command);

console.log(stdout);

kicutil/sandbox$ node test1.mjs 
file:util/sandbox/test1.mjs:11
} = await execPromise(command);
    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

Comment: @user21093656 old node version?